# Filter Collection matching fields with another List in memory

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a list in memory. I am wishing to filter a collection's items matching with that list. The scenario is like the following:

```
var memoryList = new List<MyClass>()
{
   new MyClass(){ Id = "1", Name ="aaa" },
   new MyClass(){ Id = "2", Name ="bbb" },
   new MyClass(){ Id = "3", Name ="ccc" }
};

IEnumerable<MyCollection> myDesiredItems = repository.GetItems<MyCollection>(c => memoryList.Any(m => m.Id == c.ItemId && m.Name == c.ItemName)).ToList();


public class MyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But I get **Unsupported filter: Any(...)** exception when I run my code. Any suggestion how can I achieve **myDesiredItems**?

Comment: Contains is supported so writing: `memoryList.Contains(...)`

Comment: I tried, but Contains(...) doesn't work for the scenario either.

Comment: Well, maybe the issue is in the implementation of the `GetItems` method of your repository. Make sure the `FilterDefinition` is generated properly using your expression.

Comment: I meant `Contains(...)` mostly works for the lists of primitive data types. But for the described scenario it doesn't work.